# How do I format a list a column?

Tags: python, format, list-comprehension

I need to format a list into a column.

`a = [1,2,3,4,5]`
The desired output:

```
         a
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
4        5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.format`:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print("{:<10} {:<10}".format("", "a"))
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    print("{:<10} {:<10}".format(i, v))
```

Prints:

```
           a         
0          1         
1          2         
2          3         
3          4         
4          5
```

---

Or making a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["a"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand{:<10} {:<10}, I also like to add my own format like {:6s}, also some of my columns are strings. Also, I don't like to use Pandas.

Comment: @ElsaidSamiElsaidMohamed `{:<10}` meand that I want to format string to the left (padding to 10 spaces). More info here https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align

Comment: Thanks, but why `print("{:<10}".format("a"))
for i in enumerate(a):
    print("{:<10}".format(i))`  doesn't work?